# Deploy a monthly job by add_interval_job()

Tags: python, apscheduler

In `APScheduler`, I know I can deploy a montly job by using **add_cron_job()**: `add_cron_job(my_job, day="2", kwargs=None)`, then the task will get executed on every 2nd of the month (1/2, 2/2, 3/2,...etc.)

My questions is: is it possible to achieve it by using [add_interval_job()](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/v1.3.1/modules/scheduler.html)?

> add_interval_job(func, weeks=0, days=0, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0,
>   start_date=None, repeat=0, args=None, kwargs=None)

Based on the signature, looks like I can only have it execute every 4 weeks: `add_interval_job(my_job, weeks=4)` or every 30 days: `add_interval_job(my_job, days=30)`, any ideas?

Comment: Seems to me that you have answered your own question. Since the length of months vary, you're stuck to execute a fixed date every month (`add_cron_job`) or with a fixed interval around 30 days (`add_interval_job`). It's a matter for you to decide what's more appropriate to what you need.

Comment: @RickardSjogren yeah but I'm still hoping some better solution